# Get block number / position of file on HDD (linux)

Tags: linux, hard-drive, blocking

How can I retrieve the block number(s) of a certain file in a file system (the blocks the file is using on the harddisc)?

I'm using the gentoo linux based SystemRescueCD, so I got plenty of tools installed which might get that information for me.

Best regards

Comment: What filesystem are you looking at? Is this a rescue of a Windows/NTFS system, an old FAT32 system, ext2, ext3, ext4, ReiserFS, etc.? The kind of information and tools may vary widely by filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking at Linux with ext2, ext3 or (probably) ext4, you want [e2fsprogs](http://e2fsprogs.sourceforge.net/), specifically the `debugfs` program.

For NTFS and FAT32, there may be Linux-based utils that will provide that information but you might also look into the Windows Defragmentation API, but there seems to be little information about it. [Jeffrey Wall's C# wrappers for the Windows defragmentation API](http://blogs.msdn.com/jeffrey_wall/archive/2004/09/13/229137.aspx) might be a good place to start, and the [MyDefrag](http://www.mydefrag.com) forums might also have some information of use.

Quick additional notes:

- if you're working on NTFS and can run this in Windows, the command you want is DeviceIoControl, passing the [FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS control code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364572%28VS.85%29.aspx). More information on defragmentation and the API in [Defragmenting Files (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363911%28VS.85%29.aspx).
- Here's an amusing little walkthrough of tracking things down on an NTFS partition using a hex editor, a hex calculator, <strike>copious</strike> free time and some determination: [Hex-Edit your way through the volume](http://www.linux-ntfs.org/doku.php?id=howto:hexedityourway) from the folks at the [Linux-NTFS project](http://www.linux-ntfs.org/doku.php).